# Changing Background via random number

Tags: java, libgdx

I coded a little script, where a random number (with the range of 0-1) is generated, that will change the Background based on the value. But when I start the program , the two Backgrounds are constantly switching between each other , so it looks like the screen flickers.

I wanted to use this number in a switch.
For example, when the number is 1 it should change to Background X and when it's 2 it changes to Background Y

```
            public Texture BackgroundImage;
```

in my create() method:

```
            BackgroundImage = new Texture("BackgroundImage.png");
```

in my render() method:

```
            Random random = new Random();
    int randomint = random.nextInt(2);
    switch (randomint){
        case 0:
            BackgroundImage = new 
                            Texture("background1.png");
            batch.begin();
            batch.draw(BackgroundImage, 0, 0);
            batch.end();
            break;
        case 1:
            BackgroundImage = new 
                            Texture("background2.png");
            batch.begin();
            batch.draw(BackgroundImage, 0, 0);
            batch.end();
            break;
    }
```

Comment: How often is the `render` method called? It seems like it is called more than once. Maybe you should place the code in the `create` method, too.

Comment: I put the switch statement in my create method and now it works. Thank you